# L'expression « comme par exemple » est-elle correcte?

Tags: standard, locutions

J'ai souvent lu l'expression « comme par exemple » et je me demandais si c'était une utilisation :

- correcte ;
- correcte, mais déconseillée ;
- complètement horrible et à proscrire.

On la retrouve entre autres à [quelques endroits sur le site](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22comme+par+exemple%22), un peu [partout sur Internet dans l'actualité](https://www.google.ca/search?q=comme+par+exemple&aq=f&oq=comme+par+exemple#hl=fr&tbm=nws&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22comme+par+exemple%22&oq=%22comme+par+exemple%22&gs_l=serp.3...8502.10733.1.10964.6.5.1.0.0.0.163.442.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.ALUNjyVZ7qA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.dmg&fp=fb71c61f846e86d7&biw=1600&bih=715) et probablement dans certains journaux et périodiques.

J'allais l'écrire aujourd'hui dans un rapport que j'ai à produire et je me suis dit qu'il valait mieux vérifier et mettre ça au clair avant de l'utiliser!

En voici un exemple :

> J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, **comme par exemple** le parc *Acme* à *Helloworld-sur-le-cap*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redondance utile possible : lisible, précis. Enfin, je veux dire : la redondance peut être utile, car elle peut rendre la phrase plus lisible ou plus précise.

Le mot *comme* a beaucoup de sens : il peut introduire une comparaison, une cause, ou une alternative.

> J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, comme m'allonger sur ma chaise-longue dans mon jardin.
>   J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, comme ce sont les seuls endroits sans voitures dans Paris.
>   J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, comme ma femme.

Ajouter « par exemple » impose le sens de *comme* comme introduisant un exemple.

Dans l'autre sens, *par exemple* ne fournit aucun lien grammatical, et peut être situé avant ou après l'exemple. Son utilisation peut résulter en une phrase difficile à suivre car il faut décortiquer l'empilement de clauses.

Il n'y a donc de recoupement que partiel entre *comme* et *par exemple*. S'il peut y avoir de la redondance, il n'y a pas de pléonasme. On ne peut donc le condamner à ce titre.

Il semble que [la juxtaposition de *comme* avec *par exemple*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=par+exemple%2Ccomme+par+exemple&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) soit devenue progressivement plus courante au cours du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Elle est grammaticalement correcte, et sémantiquement justifiée. Puisque l'usage la reconnaît, je ne vois aucune raison de la condamner.

Comment: Wow, j'adore l'outil de Google!

Answer (score 2):

C'est un tour qui tient du pléonasme, utiliser *comme* ou même *par exemple* seuls est généralement correct et ne modifie pas le sens de la phrase.  Ça ne m'étonnerait pas qu'il ait sa source à l'oral, où le *par exemple* permet de meubler le silence pendant qu'on cherche justement cet exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'avais pas prévu répondre à ma question au départ, mais j'ai fait un peu de recherche et je suis tombé sur un [article plutôt intéressant](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2155) de la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bdl.html), qui explique bien pourquoi l'usage de cette expression est déconseillé.

> Les enchaînements **comme par exemple** et **ainsi par exemple** [...] sont considérés comme pléonastiques.

### Un peu de théorie

Cela veut dire qu'on devrait s'en tenir à une seule des expressions à la fois. C'est soit « ainsi », ou « comme », soit « par exemple ». La locution *par exemple* peut s'utiliser dans presque tous les cas, et *ainsi* ou *comme* doivent être utilisés avec un peu plus d'attention.

De ce que j'en comprends, « comme » est vraiment utilisé pour introduire un ou plusieurs exemples tandis que « ainsi » est utilisé pour introduire un exemple ayant une conséquence, et peut donc être remplacé par « par conséquent ».

### Revenons sur la question

La phrase que j'avais mentionnée comme exemple devrait donc être remplacée par un des deux cas suivants :

> J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, **comme** le parc Acme à Helloworld-sur-le-cap.
>
> J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs, **par exemple** le parc Acme à Helloworld-sur-le-cap.

### Cas *d'exception*

> La locution conjonctive par exemple employée avec la conjonction ainsi ou comme peut parfois suggérer une forme d’insistance.

Pour utiliser les deux, il faut alors les séparer par une virgule (à l'écrit), ou une pause (à l'oral) afin d'éviter le pléonasme.

> Au cours de mes différentes interventions, j'ai vu plusieurs erreurs. **Comme, par exemple,** l'utilisation d'anglicismes.

Revenons donc, encore une fois, sur la phrase de la question, en prenant compte que l'on tienne vraiment à insister sur l'exemple qui y était donné. On peut y ajouter une virgule pour défaire le pléonasme.

> J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs. **Comme, par exemple,** le parc Acme.

On signifie ici une grande insistance sur le parc « Acme », comme quoi il est la place où on aime se promener.

Comment: Hum, « …considérés *comme* pléonastiques » et ça ose donner des leçons :-)

Comment: Sinon j'ai un doute sur l'enchaînement dans les deux solutions que tu proposes. La transcription correcte de l'oral qui ne nécessite pas de vraiment tout changer (bien qu'en fait c'est sûrement une bonne idée) c'est « *J'aime bien me promener dans les parcs. Comme, par exemple, le parc Acme*. »

Comment: Oui bien vu, je vais utiliser cet exemple dans la troisième section! *(Si jamais il y a eu deux notifications de commentaire, désolé! Il y avait une énorme faute dans l'autre)*